# How to select specific rows or the whole table efficiently using an user defined type?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having some problems using an User defined type to pass some identifiers and select several rows at the same time. 
For example

User defined type:

```
CREATE TYPE IntList AS Table (n int UNIQUE)
```

Usage with stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spBarsGet
    @lBars IntList READONLY 
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM Bars 
    WHERE id IN (SELECT n FROM @lBars)
```

When it is necessary to return all the rows from `Bars` in the table, it is possible to use the same procedure changing the query and sending an empty Bars list:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Bars 
WHERE 
   (NOT EXISTS (SELECT Null FROM @lBars) OR 
    Id IN (SELECT n FROM @lBars))
```

or this:

```
DECLARE @Aux int
SELECT @Aux = COUNT(n) FROM @lBars

SELECT * 
FROM Bars 
WHERE (@Aux = 0 OR Id IN (SELECT n FROM @lBars))
```

Both options work, however if there are several rows in the table (more than 1 million approx) the query becomes very slow. Much slower than two separated queries for each case:

Select specific Bars:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Bars 
WHERE id IN (SELECT n FROM @lBars)
```

Select all the rows in the table:

```
SELECT * FROM Bars
```

I am looking for a better (faster, efficient) way to achieve the described behavior using only one query, in this case the same stored procedure.

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: `@lBars` has the million rows or `Bars`?

Comment: Hello @stickybit,  Bars contains the million rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
SELECT b.*
FROM   Bars b
       JOIN @lBars lb ON b.Id = lb.n
UNION
SELECT b.*
FROM   Bars b
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (   SELECT 1
                      FROM   @lBars );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @AB_87. The query is quite large, includes some joins. So, if there is no other option, it will be easier to use a single query for each task

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` :

```
select *
from( (select . . . -- Qualify column name
       from bars b
       where exists (select 1 from @lBars b1 where b1.n = b.id)
      ) union all
      (select . . . -- Qualify column name
       from bars b
       where not exists (select 1 from @lBars b1 where b1.n = b.id)
      )
    ) t;
```